# how to add package to source install

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building ROS Indigo from source for a BeagleBoneBlack running U13.10 via these instructions:
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source

I was able to build ros-comm without any problems! YAY!

Now, what is the best way to also build urg_node and all it's dependencies? I hope the anwser is not to make an overlay work-space, manually git clone the source, look in package.xml for more deps, and then git clone those... I imagine that there's some way to use ws tool to automaticly pull urg_node, and it's dependancies such as sensor_msgs for building into either the existing src folder created in the above tutorial, or in an overlay on the install_isolated?

Sorry for being long winded, I just wasn't sure how to phrase the question, but I hope you get what I'm asking... ;)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144956/how-to-add-package-to-source-install/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For released packages you can use the rosinstall_generator: http://wiki.ros.org/rosinstall_generator

It looks like urg_node isn't released, so I think you'll have to do some manual work. Basically, if something isn't released, there isn't any meta-info about where to get the source, or what branch to use for indigo. I'd suggest starting at urg_node, working backwards to add dependencies, but as soon as you reach released packages use the rosinstall_generator. I tried running the rosinstall_generator on all build dependencies of urg_node, and got:

```
rosinstall_generator  --rosdistro indigo --deps roscpp rosconsole sensor_msgs nodelet dynamic_reconfigure tf laser_proc diagnostic_updater urg_c
The following not released packages/stacks will be ignored: diagnostic_updater, laser_proc, urg_c
... <lots of rosinstall stuff for the other deps>
```

Since urg_node isn't released for indigo (and doesn't even have an indigo-devel branch), i wouldn't expect it to compile right away - you'll probably have to do some hacking.

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks, Jon! based on your advice I was able to piece together the solution:

I made an overlay workspace and git clone'd in packages that were not yet building on indigo and ran catkin_make. It would then fail to build and tell me it was missing a dep. I then went back to the original source installation directory and added the package and it's deps via:

```
$ rosinstall_generator tf --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --tar > tf.rosinstall
$ wstool merge -t src tf.rosinstall
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Then try to run catkin_make in my overlay workspace again and find the next dep failure, rinse, repeat. It wan't as bad as I thought it would be ;) Just painfully slow on my little BBB, since it only has an SD card for storage and not enough ram for a ramdisk workspace... :P

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1